# Node.js authentication without passport: are json web tokens reliable?

Tags: node.js, authentication, mean-stack, json-web-token

I'm using the MEAN stack and want to make sure certain routes have an authenticated user. I've been reading up on JSON web tokens. This seems reasonable.

Before I invest anymore time into it, I want to ask if anyone else uses this and if there are any major flaws they've noticed thus far. And are there any other popular alternatives excluding passport?

Answer (score 2):

JSON web tokens have several flaws which, when dealt with properly, can make the approach quite useful for performing authorization:

- A client still needs to transmit user credentials to a authentication server, which means using secure transmissions is paramount
- If sensitive information is placed into the token, this information should be encrypted by the client and sent across a secure transmission
- Depending on how your constructing the token and who your sharing it with, tokens should have a limited lifetime, preventing others from destructuring the token since it's generation and potentially sending falsified data to servers

There are definitely other approaches to cookie-based authentication other than `passport`, but I'm not aware of any that are as well integrated and popularized, though I'm sure you might find something more efficient. There are other examples of cookie-based schemes that exists, which you could implement, for instance the [auto-login scheme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64260/how-does-sos-new-auto-login-feature-work) from SO.

If you want to invest the time to learn how to implement JWT, it would definitely be worth the effort. If your trying to asses whether you need to use JWT, a good rule of thumb is asking yourself whether you will have multiple authentication servers, will you need to authorize clients accross several different domains and whether you need the clients to have stateless/ephemeral authorization tokens.

Comment: Thank you. I'm reading the link you provided and the part that has me questioning everything is here: "StackAuth checks localStorage for a session, and sends it to itself if it is.". Could a malicious individual copy this local storage session as well and use it within their own client browser to log into other sites with the original users credentials?

Comment: Yes, but this can happen with data stored in secure cookies as well. If someone can inject their custom JS code and have this distributed to other clients, they would have the same level of access as your application code, potentially allowing them to either leak secure data elsewhere or perform actions on behalf of the user.

Comment: I see. Are there things I can do to eliminate such actions and identify  impersonations? Are there any other forms of authentication that don't come with this vulnerability?

Comment: Cookies are a storage mechanism, NOT an authentication mechanism.  Cookies can be used very securly, as a storage mechanism, espeically if you use the HTTPS-only flag on the cookie.  What you store in the cookie (JWT) is your authentication mechanism and has, as separate concern, issues like how long the token should be used for and what needs to be exchanged for that token (username and password).  I've elaborted on these issues in my blog post: [Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps (SPAs)](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

Comment: @robertjd cookies are part of an authentication mechanism, as soon as  they're used to transmit a payload which can be used to uniquely identify your authorization by secure appliances.